# How do I send JSON data from angular Json Editor to .net core webapi controller?

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an angular client that has an angular JSON editor. I have to send the JSON data (from the editor) to a .NET Core Web API controller and there I have to perform tasks like writing it into a JSON file. How do I approach this? I need help and more with the controller.

Comment: You should add the relevant code you already have (in angular and in your controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to send the JSON data (from the editor) to a .NET Core Web API controller and there I have to perform tasks like writing it into a JSON file. How do I approach this?

To achieve the above requirement, you can refer to following code snippet.

*Angular client*

```
@ViewChild(JsonEditorComponent) editor: JsonEditorComponent;

options = new JsonEditorOptions();
data = {
  name: "fei",
  age: 28
};

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  this.options.mode = "code";
  this.options.modes = ["code", "text", "tree", "view"];
  this.options.schema = schema;
  this.options.statusBar = false;
  this.options.onChange = () => console.log(this.editor.get());
}

InsertUser() {
  const updatedJson = this.editor.get();
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json");

  this.httpClient
    .post("https://xxxxx/Insert", JSON.stringify(updatedJson), {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: "text"
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

*Controller and Action*

```
[HttpPost("/Insert")]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertUser(User User)
{
    //...

    return Ok("success");
}
```

*Model class `User`*

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Hi Fei Han, thank you so much for your help. Just one follow up question, here we have a model that is already defined. What if we we have to send a random JSON file. In that case, how will the controller action look like. Here you have already defined the User model. That way the controller can accept any JSON data.